# python не видит функцию osmium а

Tags: python

Я начал изучать OSM (openstreetmap). Osmium это, вроде каК, хорошая библиотека которая помогает работать с форматом pbf (такой формат osm). С [оф. страницы](https://docs.osmcode.org/pyosmium/latest/intro.html#reading-osm-data) я решил вставить себе код

```
import osmium

class CounterHandler(osmium.SimpleHandler):
  def __init__(self):
    osmium.SimpleHandler.__init__(self)
    self.num_nodes = 0

  def node(self, n):
    self.num_nodes += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
  h = CounterHandler()
  h.apply_file("C:/Users/Алексей/Desktop/Python fun/OpenStreetMap/map/siberian-fed-district-latest.osm.pbf")
  print("Number of nodes: %d" % h.num_nodes)
```

но при его выполнении выдает ошибку:

> ... line 15, in 
>       h.apply_file("C:/Users/Алексей/Desktop/Python fun/OpenStreetMap/map/siberian-fed-district-latest.osm.pbf")
>   AttributeError: 'CounterHandler' object has no attribute 'apply_file'

Что нужно сделать, чтобы он увидел эту функцию из osmium?

Comment: SimpleHandler импортируется через __ c двух сторон. Этот класс не поддерживает наследования в том виде, что Вы написали.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Немного не понял. Во первых у меня и с __ не получается, а еще, как не в том виде, если на официальном сайте так написано..? Как в таком случае мне стоит сделать?

Comment: @lamready смотрите исходники самой библиотеки. Там довольно мудрёно прописывается в __init__.py ... Просто так такие объекты не перетягиваются.  Доступ к свойствам объекта получить можно, но не в том виде как у Вас написано. Как точно - сейчас не скажу :)

Comment: Вообщем то разработчики библиотеки Вас предупредили, что не хотели бы, чтобы Вы наследовали классы так как у Вас сейчас. Мол читайте как оно работает. Это всё последствия попыток сделать приватные методы в python :)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич А как же мне пользоваться программой, если я не могу воспользоваться её же функцией? Как импортировать?

Comment: Ну можете пользоваться самим SimpleHandler например. Проведите экперемент, должно работать. Проблема именно в наследовании.

Comment: Да я другого способа пользоваться и не знаю.. Не могли бы показать иной вариант пользования функцией SimpleHandler, без такого наследования?